# Escaping quotes in javascript function

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to pass a variable to a javascript function. Depending on the user choice, it can be a text or an image. Similar issue has been discussed here, yet I am unable to solve this.

In php, I am coding like this:

```
if ($choice == 1) {
    $img = '<img src = "../folder/'.$_SESSION["img"].'">';
    $hdrs .= "'".$img."','".$_SESSION['id']."'";
} else {
    $hdrs = "'".$txt."','".$_SESSION['id']."'";
}
echo '<button type = "button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" onclick = "dothis('.$hdrs.');"> OK</button>';
```

The generated html should be something like this, but it is not correct.

```
<button type = "button"  class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" onclick = "dothis('<img src = "../folder/file.jpg">','15');">OK</button>';
```

I tried to escape with backslash `\'` and `\"` , but they don't work. What is the way around?

Comment: Have you tried \\\' and \\\".

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your following code. The reason the backslash didn't worked because of quotes conflict.

```
if ($choice == 1) { 
  //$img = '<img src = "../folder/'.$path.'">';
    $img = "<img src = \'../folder/" . $_SESSION["img"] . "\'>";
    $hdrs .= "'" . $img . "','" . $_SESSION["id"] . "'"; 
} else {
    $hdrs = "'" . $txt . "','" . $_SESSION["id"] . "'"; 
} 
echo '<button type = "button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" onclick = "dothis(' . $hdrs . ');"> OK</button>';
```